# xam.plugin.geolocator doesn't work in ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i try to listen when the position change ,the app detect it .
with android it works well , but in ios it's not working
i have followed this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=ios

```
async Task StartListening()
        {
            await DisplayAlert("1", "moving", "OK");

            await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10, true, new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ListenerSettings
            {
                ActivityType = Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
                AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
                DeferLocationUpdates = true,
                DeferralDistanceMeters = 1,
                DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                ListenForSignificantChanges = true,
                PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

            });
            await DisplayAlert("2", "moving", "OK");

            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += PositionChangedAsync;
        }
```

the first alert works but the second doesn't work .
please need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the shared code in my local site, and it works.

Make sure that your `info.plist` should contain something like this:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when open and in the background.</string>
```

Comment: thank you i was putting the keys without `<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>`

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue.

Running on iOS 14, CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync displays a popup stating that the app is using background location and gives option to keep that permission or change it to use in app only.

On selecting an option (any option), CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync never returns and subsequent code doesnt execute.

If I kill the app and restart it with the permissions manually set the callback works.

Comment: Mine was solved by making sure I have LocationAlways permission set before starting to listen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66142170/xam-plugin-geolocator-never-returns-on-first-run-ios-14