# Xam.Plugin.Geolocator never returns on first run iOS 14

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using the CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync method in my xamarin app to be able to listen to location updates in background for iOS.

I am using essentials to request permissions.

On first run we get location permission (in app only) and location using essentials and then we use StartListeningAsync for ios to be able to track location if the app is in background or foreground.

When the callback is hit we get a popup saying this app uses background location and gives you the option to use it or change back to use in app only option. On selection of any option the callback never completes and subsequent code isnt run.

Here is the popup I get after I have permission for when in use and then start listening:

[Popup on ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lamzo.png)

On subsequent runs once permissions are set manually the callback works.

Xamarin Forms Version: 5.0.0.1931
Xamarin Essential Version: 1.6.1
Geolocator Plugin Version: 4.6.2-beta
Code example:

```
    private async Task StartListening()
    {
        if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
            return;

        try
        {
            var settings = new ListenerSettings
            {
                ActivityType = ActivityType.Other,
                DeferLocationUpdates = true,
                DeferralDistanceMeters = 15,
                DeferralTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                ListenForSignificantChanges = false,
                PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false,
                AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
            };
            
            await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), 5, true, settings);
            
            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += PositionChanged;
            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError += PositionError;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, you need to ask permission before starting to listen to location updates. If the permission is well, then invoke `StartListening` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the permission is ok before starting to listen to location updates. Have a try with following code:

```
public async Task GetLocationAsync()
{
    var status = await CheckAndRequestPermissionAsync(new Permissions.LocationAlways());
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        // Notify user permission was denied
        return;
    }else{
        await StartListening();
    }
}

public async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckAndRequestPermissionAsync<T>(T permission)
            where T : BasePermission
{
    var status = await permission.CheckStatusAsync();
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        status = await permission.RequestAsync();
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I already have the permission for when in use by the time I start listening. I think the problem comes in because I am requesting to allow background updates. So on calling CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync I get another popup from the system, the one saying should you continue to use background location with yes/no option. I will attach a screen shot in an answer, cant seem to do it in the comment.

Comment: Image attached in origional question.

Comment: @user2641023 Okey, you mean the shared option of background location interrupts the callback of listener. If so, you could ask for this: `Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationAlways>();` to check whehter that popup will show later.

Comment: yes, sorry for the round about way of getting to the point. Im not sure why it asks this though? Ok I will start listening only after I know I have location always. WIll give feedback shortly if this works.

Comment: Ok so yes in my case making sure that I have LocationAlways before listening is the correct solution. Thanks @JuniorJiang.